# Why are Apple Watch's local notifications delayed?

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, apple-watch, watchos-6

I created an app for Apple Watch with a companion app for iPhone. These two apps test the local notifications on both devices.

But since I updated to iOS 13.1.2 and WatchOS 6.0.1, the local notifications on Apple are delayed: when I press the button on the watch that creates the notification and I exit the app, it doesn't take 5 seconds to display the notification but about 20 seconds... when I change the code to 3 seconds it takes 16 secs to display.

Is this a new feature on Apple Watch or a bug? Because on iPhone it works without any delay.

Thank you in advance :)

```
    // Configure the notification's payload.
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello!", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello_message_body", arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "FiveSecond", content: content, trigger: trigger) // Schedule the notification.
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
         if let theError = error {
             // Handle any errors
         }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I also noticed this strange behavior: when I create a notification on iPhone, pressing the button and then put the phone on stand by so the notification gets delivered to Apple Watch, the notifications gets displayed correctly after 5 seconds on the watch!

Comment: Do longer notifications e.g. 5 minutes or 30 minutes deliver on schedule? I could imagine this is a resolution issue, e.g. the notification loop only runs every so many seconds, or there's a deliberate block on apps firing a notification as soon as you close them - what's the use case for that?

Comment: I'm using WatchConnectivity to make apple watch create the notification, in didReceiveUserInfo i put the code. Also i'm using Extended Runtime Sessions to make the app work in background.
But instead of creating a notification, i create a vibration on the watch, there isn't a delay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated my Apple Watch to WatchOS 6.1 and yes... they fixed the bug!!!
Now the notifications created locally get triggered on time :)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this also on local notifications generated on the watch.
I have generated notifications from 30 seconds to 3 minutes (in 30 second increments), and they are consistently about 13 seconds late.
Before watchOS 6, they were not late.